# Macbook air mid-2011 visual glitch problem

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I face some problems with my macbook air mid 2011 (HD 3000), some weird visual glitch on the screen (see pictures).

*Is there any solution or fix? Does anyone else have the same issue?*

I own a Apple care(june 2014).

I have already contacted Apple, they done a Hardware test and the test revealed nothing so they do not believe me completely... And they don't know what to do (**seriously**) ...

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Sorry for my bad English: i am French =).

[image: glitch 1]

[image: glitch 2]

[image]

[image: This appear only during the initialization of the rendering/test]

[image]

This appear only during the initialization of the rendering/test

Comment: Your French is pretty good, so we understand you. Still have a few questions. Please specify in which program do you see the problem.

Comment: Mail Aperture Safari Finder. I am at your entire disposal

Comment: Hmm ...all of those ? Does the preview do it as well ?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it. But Yes the Preview app glitch as well ! i add a third screenshot !

Comment: Great, one more question, when you play a video, is it working correctly?

Comment: It is after midnight for me, so sorry have to go, but please check if your video is working. Please check if you have enough free memory >1Gig, since I see you have a lot of programs open and the MacBook Air might be suffering. So close all programs -including the background and try the preview again.

Comment: Yes i have enough free (25 go) space in the SSD drive. When i work on my photos the 4 Go of RAM are full, Aperture(+Nik softwares) is Open and Photoshop Safari and Mail. I always work like that. And closing some App to avoid graphical issue is unacceptable (No?), of course closing an App in order to reduces delays&swap is acceptable. Glitch appear (more rarely) even when the is no swap and 2go of Ram are free(inactive) . I watch film in streaming and in vlc quite often and no videos glitch . Thank for your dutifully have a good night.

Comment: I hope you can come back tomorrow. Again thanks you

Comment: It's possible that you have bad RAM. Did you do a recent upgrade?

Comment: "I'm having this problem too" comment: Macmini6,2

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion and some fact finding above:

I would say your hardware is fine /the Intel HD3000, but it could be on its way out!, means it could be dying the slow death.

You can double check and run a stress test for the GPU [using this little program](http://www.geeks3d.com/20131029/gputest-0-6-1-bugfix-release-for-mac-os-x/), or look for your OSX version.

GpuTest 0.6.1 is a bugfix release for Mac OS X only. The CSV file (for benchmark scores) was no longer generated at the end of a benchmark. This CSV file is stored in the root folder of the current user (_geeks3d_gputest_scores.csv).

[image]

[image]

However, I still think you have a software (programs) interference issue.
Remember the Intel GPU uses shared memory, so that could lead to a problem you are having.

Finding out which program is interfering could be tricky, but you had to just turn them completely off one at the time.

In your case I recommend:

Use an external monitor (or LCD Television) to:

1-see if it is a problem with the build in display

2a problem with the flat band cable to the build in display

3-actual problem with the GPU chip

Comment: Thank you. I bench my GPU with GpuTest 0.6.1. Glitch appear during initialization, and disappear after (during the rendering/test). Due to my lack on english skill , i don't completely understand "your hardware is fine /the Intel HD3000, but it could be on its way out!" ... Can you explain in other word ? I put the result of the bench and a screenshot of the glitch in the first message.

Comment: That benchmark shows you have a big problem. I meant to say your GPU might be Dying the slow death :(. Also see my update above.

Comment: Which problem ? From the bench score you can deduce something ? The weird glitches windows appears only 3-4 seconds,then a kind a of orange Donut appears and move.

Comment: There is no ONLY situation, there should be ZERO glitches at any time = Never!

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i feel more confident. Tomorrow, i will contact one more time the Apple Care staff, i will me more sure of myself and uncompromising with them ,thanks to you ;).

Comment: I contact Apple the send me their Capture Data App. It a app that collect data of your machine and make a repport.dmg. Once the repport.dmg is created you have to send it back. Then some engineers looks into this repport.dmg and tell you what is wrong or not. In my case they said that the problem is due to Adobe flash player and Tomb Raider 2 (download from the App store) ... So their is nothing Hardware . Of course the bug appear on a clean partition 10.7.5 (with no new app). For me it's a denial of warranty. And i don't know what to do. Can you help me ?

Comment: Update to Adobe Flash player 12. Then uninstall the Tomb Raider. The problem should disappear according to App store !! The Adobe is a standard so it should not make any problems, The Tomb Rider could make problems like that due to them using they drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Finder and for me the solution was that I quit Google Drive app.

Answer (score -1):

try restarting your mac. mine did this all of a sudden, and i found this, tried restarting, and its fine now. mine looked just like your pictures (when i looked at them after the restart). if this doesn't solve it, try mailing it to apple, take it to an apple store, or open yourself (no recommended as this will void the warranty). you may have to buy a new processor, or even a new graphics card. Or just restart :)